# What column type in Laravel is ideal to store values from 0 to 60 and how do I mitigate the excess storage space

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What datatype will be ideal to store values from 0 to 60 in the database? The options I've seen according to the documentation are `$table->unsignedTinyInteger('votes');` and `$table->unsignedSmallInteger('votes');` But even at this, I think it's too big a size for what is needed.

So, is there a way to specify the amount of values I can store in a column?

Documentation ref: [Laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#columns)

Answer (score 2):

Stick with `unsigned tiny int`. Its size is 1 byte ( so it'd take 1 million+ entries to reach 1MB ). Trying to over optimize column datatypes would just lead to a lot of headaches in the future.